# Tidy up excel function

Tags: excel

I have an excel function that does the job I want but can probably be tidied up:

```
=CELL("contents",E2) & (", ") & CELL("contents",F2) & (", ") & CELL("contents",G2 )& (", ") & CELL("contents",H2)
```

It grabs the info from four cells in a row and adds a comma and space between each one.

How can I tidy it up? Also how can I put that formula in all 126 without changing the cell references to "E3, F3, G3, H3" then "E4, F4, G4, H4" and so on.

Comment: Write the formula in one cell, then drag the cell to the neighboring ones - Excel will adjust the cell coordinates for you.

Comment: Along Marc's suggestion; remember that if you *dont* want the references to change when you drag it, to use $A$2 (for example). This locks both row and column. If you only want to lock one, you can do A$2 or $A2.

Comment: Why are you using `CELL("Contents", ` rather than just `=E2&","&F2&","&G2&","&H2` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simpler:

```
=E2 & ", " & F2 & ", " & G2 & ", " & H2
```

You could also write a VBA function to mimic the .NET string.Join() function, and then the formula would be

```
=JOIN(E2:H2)
```

Or perhaps, depending on how you write the function:

```
=JOIN(E2:H2, ", ")
```

As commenters have noted, if you copy and paste the above formulas, Excel will adjust the cell references to keep the relative relationship with the new location.

Here's a possible implementation of JOIN():

```
Public Function JOIN(rngValues As Range, strSeparator As String) As String
    Dim rngCell As Range

    For Each rngCell In rngValues
        If Not IsEmpty(rngCell) Then
            If Len(JOIN) Then
                JOIN = JOIN & strSeparator
            End If
            JOIN = JOIN & rngCell
        End If
    Next
End Function
```